# XPath over more levels

Tags: html, xpath, jmeter

is it possible with xpath to extract something in another Level ?

In my table there are diffrent diffrent rows . In one if it there is my row where somewhere is print "bpmtestinstanz". I need to get the URL (href) of the the Link where is "Instanz abbauen" in the Link and in the table-row (tr)  "bpmtestinstanz" inside . But I don't know how i should handle xpath over the diffrent levels of the Link and the printed text .

```
<tr class="htmlobject_tr even" onclick="tr_click(this, 'idp54bf6c72037f1')" onmouseover="tr_hover(this, 'idp54bf6c72037f1')" onmouseout="tr_hover(this, 'idp54bf6c72037f1')">

<td class="htmlobject_td state">
<span class="pill active">
active</span>
</td>

<td class="htmlobject_td config">
<b>
Request ID</b>
 14218305642887<br>
<b>
Hostname</b>
 bpmtestinstanz<br>
<b>
Typ</b>
 KVM VM (localboot)<br>
<b>
CPU</b>
 1<br>
<b>
Speicher</b>
 1.024 GB<br>
<b>
Kernel</b>
 default<br>
<b>
Festplatte</b>
 5 GB<br>
<b>
Image</b>
 13982361680940.cloud_14218305642887_1_<br>
<b>
IP</b>
 192.168.200.166, 172.26.41.105</td>

<td class="htmlobject_td comment">
Requested by user danieldrichardt<hr>
<a class="plugin console" onclick="sshwindow = window.open('https://172.26.41.105:8022','window1722641105', 'location=0,status=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=973,height=500,left=100,top=100,screenX=400,screenY=100'); sshwindow.focus(); return false;" href="#">
Ajaxterm</a>
<a class="plugin novnc" target="_blank" href="api.php?action=novnc&amp;appliance_id=14218305990082">
noVNC</a>
</td>

<td class="htmlobject_td action">
<a data-message="" class="pause" title="Instanz pausieren" href="index.php?cloud_ui=pause&amp;cloudappliance_id[]=14218308730556">
Instanz pausieren</a>
<a data-message="" class="restart" title="Instanz neu starten" href="index.php?cloud_ui=restart&amp;cloudappliance_id[]=14218308730556">
Instanz neu starten</a>
<a data-message="" class="private" title="Privates Image anlegen" href="index.php?cloud_ui=image_private&amp;appliance_id=14218305990082">
Privates Image anlegen</a>
<a data-message="" class="edit" title="Instanz bearbeiten" href="index.php?cloud_ui=appliance_update&amp;cloudappliance_id=14218308730556">
Instanz bearbeiten</a>
<a data-message="" class="remove" title="Instanz abbauen" href="index.php?cloud_ui=deprovision&amp;cloudappliance_id[]=14218308730556">
Instanz abbauen</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, but it's slightly complicated.

```
//tr[td[@class = 'htmlobject_td config' and contains(b[contains(., 'Hostname')]
/following-sibling::text()[1],'bpmtestinstanz')]]/td[@class = 'htmlobject_td action']
/a[contains(.,'Instanz abbauen')]/@href
```

which means

```
//tr[td[@class = 'htmlobject_td config'             Select all `tr` elements anywhere in
                                                    the document, but only if they have
                                                    at least one `td` child element that
                                                    has a `class` attribute with the
                                                    value "htmlobject_td config"
and contains(b[contains(., 'Hostname')]             and only if this `td` child element
                                                    also has a child element `b` whose
                                                    text value contains "Hostname"
/following-sibling::text()[1],'bpmtestinstanz')]]   and if the first following sibling
                                                    of this `b` element which is a text
                                                    node contains "bpmtestinstanz"
/td[@class = 'htmlobject_td action']                of this `tr` select a child `td`
                                                    element that has a `class` attribute
                                                    with the value "htmlobject_td action"
/a[contains(.,'Instanz abbauen')]/@href             and select its child `a` if its text
                                                    contains "Instanz abbauen" - and
                                                    finally select the `href` attribute
                                                    of this `a` element.
```

This solution requires "bpmtestinstanz" to be immediately after `<b>Hostname</b>`. If it can appear anywhere in the `tr` element, you can somewhat simplify the expression.

Comment: Its everytime after the <b>Hostname</b> . Helps me alot. thanks :)

Comment: @user3392820 You are welcome. Also have a look at the explanation, if you like.